# Div tela inteira com Bootstrap?

Tags: css, bootstrap-3

Estou tentando criar um `div` na tela inteira que vai servir como um `loading`, mas estou tendo um problema pq no `<header>` eu tenho um `navbar` que defini como `navbar-fixed-top` e a `div` não cobre esta área do header. Quando eu retiro essa propriedade `navbar-fixed-top` funciona, mas o `navbar` não fica fixo no topo.

Como faço para que a `div` cubra toda a área inclusive o `<header>` ?

**CSS**

```
.div_loading  {    
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:11;
    background-color:#000;
    width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    height:auto;
    opacity: .50;
    filter: alpha(opacity=65);
}
```

**Header(Navbar)**

```
<header>     
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top bg-red" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <h1 class="text-white">MeuSite</h1>
            </div>
            @Html.Partial("_LoginForm")
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

**Div Loading**

```
<div class="div_loading"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá! Basta você usar o z-index!
Na sua classe de loading, ponha um valor maior e na classe da navbar, ponha um valor menor, com !important
CSS:

```
.navbar, .navbar-fixed-top, .navbar-defeault {
z-index:1!important;
}
.div_loading  {    
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:2;
    background-color:#000;
    width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    height:auto;
    opacity: .50;
    filter: alpha(opacity=65);
}
```

[DEMO JsFidle](https://jsfiddle.net/kdv4quzg/1/)

Comment: perfeito, mt obrigado !